# Import errors when importing keras and tensorflow in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, ordereddict

I installed python 3.7. Then gave the pip command for install Jupyter. Then pip upgrade notification came and I upgraded pip. Then Jupyter notebook also installed.

Then in my application I wanted to import keras library. Then I install it in the relevant script folder in  python. Then I try to execute** import keras**.Then said module tensorflow not found. Same way I installed tensorflow also. After that when try to import keras or tensorflow it gives

**ImportError: cannot import name 'OrderedDict' from 'typing'**

[image]

Hope a solution for this.Instead of colabs I tried to work with jupyter currently. I have a large dataset to train.

Comment: Which exact version of Python and TensorFlow did you install?

Comment: Python 3.7 installed.For tensorflow didn't give a specific version.

Comment: I said exact version, Python 3.7 has multiple releases: 3.7.1, 3.7.2, etc. TensorFlow requires Python 3.7.2 at least.

Comment: Thanks Dr.Snoopy Somehow I uninstall that and installed 3.8.4. Then its Okay.Can I know the reason for not supporting the 3.7.1 ?

Comment: OrderedDict was added in Python 3.7.2

Comment: Ah Okay Dr.Snoopy

Answer (score 0):

`TensorFlow` is not installed in your system properly. Please follow the instructions mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) to install the TensorFlow.

Then import the `TensorFlow` and `keras` as below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
from tensorflow import keras
```